# Consuming REST API into BW/4HANA?

Tags: odata, hana, sap-bw

I am new to the world of APIs. I am trying to utilize a REST API to GET and POST from a certain website and persist those values once a day into a SAP HANA table via SDI replication. I was able to successfully test the API in Postman using a JSON file for my parameters. Now I'm unsure of the next step of how to put it all together and get it into our HANA system.

Comment: we are speaking about on-premise or cloud BW/4HANA?

Comment: on-premise, thank you